# StoredProc: Table depending on parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tons of StoredProcedures, which have to read and write from different tables, depending on a parameter they're called with.

So basically it's like:

```
CREATE myStoredProc @Scheme char(10) = ''
AS 
BEGIN
  IF @Scheme = 'Scheme1'
  BEGIN
     UPDATE Scheme1.TableA
     -- and much more logic --
  END
  IF @Scheme = 'Scheme2'
  BEGIN
     UPDATE Scheme2.TableA
     -- and much more logic --
  END
END
```

The logic in both IFs is equal, except the schemes of the tables, they're working with (and some other Parameters in WHERE-clauses, which is not a problem at all).

How could this code be made a little tighter? 
Because every change in the logic has to be done twice and due to that there is a risk of mistakes. If there would be another scheme in future, the code would expand again. Furthermore its more difficult to read,..

Thanks in advance for any ideas & best practices!

Comment: You could look at using dynamic SQL, and using @Scheme to populate the scheme in the query, this would mean you only have one query, and anything that is passed to the stored proc would generate SQL you could then execute. If there are differences in the WHERE clause however, you would need to use an IF to add the corresponding WHERE clause to the rest of the logic.

Comment: yep, dynamic SQL is an idea i've already had. advantage, less code (logic just once) - disadvantage, more difficult to test. I am curious if there are any other options (i'm just not thinking about) to solve my issue too.

Comment: Why do you say it is more difficult to test?

Comment: @Leonidas199x: sorry, i didn't explain. with dynamic SQL i've to put the SQL into strings, so there won't be syntax highlighting anymore. in addition i'd have to use PRINT a statement while testing, as i won't see the SQL before executed.